# Change class input value through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating table with input boxes and have used the following code to create new row.

I want new row should have blank values inside textboxes. For it I have tried class property to change but its not working and always get value from first row.

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
              document.getElementsByClassName('small')[0].setAttribute("value", ""); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The code searches all elements of the `document`. You can also use `getElementsByClassNamedocument` on a specific element. Untested, but you could try `newcell.getElementsByClassName(` instead (although better yet would be to loop through all elements after the loop with `row.getElementsByClassName` )

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of your first row only like so:
`document.getElementsByClassName('small')[0].setAttribute("value", "");`

You need to loop through them all and set their values.

`document.getElementsByClassName('small'),forEach(item => item.setAttribute('value','');`

Answer (score 0):

The value property does exactly what you need and works correctly in all scriptable browsers.

```
var input = document.getElementById("your_input");
input.value = "blah";
```

In your case, you can try-

```
document.getElementsByClassName('small')[0].value = "";
```

Comment: same result for this